# Is there a way to access the file in a "Open file dialog window" without using the mouse?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, mouse, gui, keyboard-navigation

Is there a way to access the file in a "Open file dialog window" without using the mouse and/or without typing the entire filename?

[image]
I was thinking of [Tab] but it doesn't work. Right now "down arrow" works but I was wondering if there is another key we could press instead of the down arrow (since it isn't very accessible)

To rephrase the question: my cursor is on that "file name:" input box, and i type `lin` and it drops down a drop down box which shows "Links". How do I access that first item in the drop down box. meaning opening `Links` without having to continue typing it's full name i.e. `ks`

If I use the mouse and click the item in the dropdown box, it works but is there a way to access it using the keyboard and not the "down button" because it isn't very accessible.

Comment: two shift+tab works just fine for me...

Comment: @soandos take a look at the edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does work, but, it is quite a bit later in the Tab Order. However, the `File Name` input box is the one straight after, so, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by any arrow key to select the file.

Alternatively, if you want to try <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, it is the 8th in the tab order, so press <kbd>Tab</kbd> 8 times.

Comment: sry this is off-point, take a look at the edit.

Comment: Seen the edit... Down is the only key I know of. You can always set an ahk script to map down to another key.